# Unity2D - OnMouseDown() doesn't work well (Sometimes work sometimes not)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently I made an object with OnMouseDown() function, and I have added Box Collider. This is my code:

```
    void OnMouseDown(){
    player.transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    print ("Hit");

}
```

That code didn't run well, sometimes work sometimes not (I know from Hit message in console). Sometimes it only works once, sometimes from the first it won't work. BUT, if I REMOVE this code:

```
player.transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
```

The script runs well and the console always gives me "Hit" every I click the object.

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Check if with the transform the box collider get's moved away. This is my current best guess without debugging.

Comment: I don't know about unity but in most game engine frameworks you can't just set the transformation like this if a phisics engine is attached.. like Yosh wrote: most likely your hitbox won move with the other object.. I would recomand looking in a turtorial

Comment: @YoshSynergi yes the box collider follows the object. And I tried to change the size of the box collider while debugging, and It works! But after that, it didn't work again and if I change the size of the box collider again it works again... lol what happen actually?

Comment: Ouh, never mind. I got the solution! I don't know why but my background or tilemaps also has the box collider. Then I delete it and it works! Thank you for your responds :)